# How can I tell the adapter ViewPager2 to redraw elements?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

My app contains viewpager and tablayout. It requests data from the server, sorts and gives each tab its own set of information. I don't want to have a request to the network every time I select a tab, so I made a host fragment that makes a request to the network and creates tabs. But when the data arrives, the view is already rendered. I give the data through the bundle to the ViewPagerAdapter. The first tab does not update the data. How can I tell the adapter to redraw a particular element?

**HostFragment**

```
    private val tabsTitles by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        listOf("All", "Analytics", "Android",  "Management")
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val departmentTabLayout = view.findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.departmentTabLayout)
        val departmentViewPager = view.findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.departmentViewPager)
        val adapter = TabsAdapter(childFragmentManager, lifecycle)

        departmentViewPager.adapter = adapter
        attachTabs(departmentTabLayout, departmentViewPager)

        departmentHostViewModel.listUsers.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            adapter.getUsers(it.items)
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
    }
    private fun attachTabs(departmentTabLayout: TabLayout, departmentViewPager: ViewPager2) {
        TabLayoutMediator(departmentTabLayout, departmentViewPager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = tabsTitles[position]
        }.attach()
    }
```

**TabsAdapter**

```
class TabsAdapter(
    fm: FragmentManager,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle,
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifecycle) {
    private val listDepartments = listOf(
        "all",
        "analytics",
        "android",
        "management"
    )
    private val listUsers: MutableList<User> = mutableListOf()

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        val departmentFragment = DepartmentFragment()
        return when (position) {
            0 -> {
                departmentFragment.arguments = bundleOf(DepartmentFragment.LIST_USERS to listUsers)
                return departmentFragment
            }
            else -> {
                departmentFragment.arguments =
                    bundleOf(DepartmentFragment.LIST_USERS to listUsers.filter { it.department == listDepartments[position] })
                return departmentFragment
            }
        }
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listDepartments.count()
    }

    fun getUsers(listUsers2: List<User>) {
        listUsers.addAll(listUsers2)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Comment: technically you need to improve the design, you are not supposed to update the user list which is inside your department fragment from view pager adapter, better way is to put or fetch the user list inside you fragment

Comment: @PreethiRao But then each tab will go to the network. The server gives only 1 list with information on all tabs. Then each tab will get the same lists. Wouldn't that be redundant?

Comment: they before loading view pager load the data and then load your viewpager